# An error when extracting the specific data using scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am novice  of python and scrapy.

```
<a data-install="355 万" data-like="792" data-name="来往" data-pn="com.alibaba.android.babylon" class="install-btn " rel="nofollow" style="display:block;" href="http://apps.wandoujia.com/apps/com.alibaba.android.babylon/download" download="来往.apk" data-track="taginfo-ndownload-com.alibaba.android.babylon">下载</a>
```

I want to extract the href. My code is:

```
...
sel = Select(response)
url = sel.xpath('//a[@class="install-btn"]/@href').extract()
...
```

BUT, the result is empty...

I don't know why. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try
`url = sel.xpath('//a[contains(@class,"install-btn")]/@href').extract()`

Comment: `url = sel.xpath('//a[contains(@class,"install-btn")]/@href').extract()`

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, using CSS selector and Scrapy's `::attr()` functional pseudo element:

```
url = sel.css('a.install-btn::attr(href)').extract()
```